# Payza "buy now" buttons

Tags: paypal, payment, forms

I' m working on a site and I need integration with `Payza`. From what I read the "buy now" button looks like this:

```
<form action="https://secure.payza.com/checkout" method="post"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="ap_amount" value="50" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ap_purchasetype" value="item-goods" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ap_merchant" value="mymail@payza.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ap_itemname" value="The Name" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ap_currency" value="USD" />
  <input type="image" name="ap_image" src="https://www.payza.com/images/payza-buy-now.png" />
</form>
```

It's insecure. Does `Payza` provide any API to secure my buttons (like `Paypal`'s NVP) or is there any way to secure buttons on my server?

Comment: What do you mean with "it's insecure? It uses https, so where is the problem?

Comment: Any user can edit the html form. Example: for item which costs 50$ the user can set the price to 5$

Answer (score 3):

The form you have in your post is using what is called "Advanced Integration". However, what is usually recommended for most sellers/merchants is "Standard Integration". Standard Integration makes sense in most cases unless you have very specific needs (more on Advanced Integration further below).

With Standard Integration, you would create the buttons in Payza's Member's Area, during which you define all the parameters, such as the amount etc., then it generates a form for you.

Unlike the Advanced Integration form, this form does not contain the price or any other information. It only has a reference ID that the Payza system will use to retrieve the information that you have set for that button. This means that the user cannot change parameters such as the amount. So I believe this is effectively what you are looking for.

Here is an example of what a Standard Integration form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.payza.com/checkout">
    <input type="hidden" name="ap_productid" value="jf3akAf34JasfkAFad4e3a==" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ap_quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="image" name="ap_image" src="https://secure.payza.com/PayNow/4A13EKMCI42KCIKAL34HZI34KL3LN1BOa9en.gif" />
</form>
```

You can find the information page about Standard Integration here:

- https://dev.payza.com/integration-tools/html-integration/standard-integration

---

Here is a little more information about Advanced Integration.

We recommend using Advanced Integration only for very specific needs, namely to have dynamically generated buttons or, for example, if the price of an item or service is dynamically determined.
If you choose to use Advanced Integration, it is critical that your systems check the information of the received payments, including the amount paid. It is recommended to check via an IPN handler. For more information, please see the section "Advanced Button Security & IPN" in the first page below, and the second page has information regarding best practices:

- https://dev.payza.com/integration-tools/html-integration/advanced-integration
- https://dev.payza.com/integration-tools/html-integration/integration-best-practices

---

That said, we have opened an internal ticket for the concerns that you have brought up.

Although Advanced Integration was implemented this way by design, we will investigate ways that we could further improve this feature.

Thank you for your post.

Comment: I also tried the standard integration and on my ipn listener I received: [listener]/?ap_itemcode=1&ap_itemname=National Geographic&ap_shippingcharges=0.00&ap_additionalcharges=0.00&ap_taxamount=0.00&ap_discountamount=0.00&ap_totalamount=10.00&ap_ipnversion=0&ap_feeamount=0.0&ap_netamount=0.0&ap_transactiontype=purchase but I have no information about the transaction number
ap_alerturl=[ipn_listener]&ap_transactiondate=2014-11-10 06:28:30
ap_status=Success

Comment: When I try the advanced integration I send this http get request: https://secure.payza.com/ipn2.ashx?token=<token> and the response is "Invalid token"

Comment: My mistake. I shouldn't send the http get request to https://secure.payza.com/ipn2.ashx because I'm testing in sandbox. What is the correct url to send the token back

Comment: I should send them to https://sandbox.payza.com/sandbox/ipn2.ashx. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

In response to your further questions:

If your IPN's do not contain reference numbers, I suspect you are using our IPN simulator. With the IPN simulator a reference number is not generated as no funds are actually transacted, thus one is not sent in the IPN data. Additionally, please note if you have Test Mode enabled within your Sandbox account, no IPN’s are generated for Test Mode transactions.

If you are using our Sandbox environment your IPN handler should post the IPN token back to the following URL: `https://sandbox.payza.com/sandbox/ipn2.ashx` . If you are continuing to receive an Invalid Token please check the following:

1. Ensure that you have IPN v 2 enabled in your Sandbox account.
2. Review your Handler to verify that you are receiving the token.
3. Review your IPN Handler script to ensure it is receiving the token and completing the URL-encoding with the token string before sending us the string back.

For more information regarding IPN trouble shooting please click on the following link:

- https://dev.payza.com/integration-tools/html-integration/ipn-guide-v2

After checking the above, if you continue to experience difficulty please send us an email providing a brief explanation, along with the email address associated with your Sandbox account so that we can investigate further.

Comment: I disabled test mode in merchant's and client's account and I still get "Invalid Token". This is what I receive: token=Ol9iQHrpsqdMslcnMlJJyGayVDs5gWZbjNBjlkeRI0DQ5nASh8mj7u/u3amfn2Q2mLF0Aq4FhfipNO6DZCHXJA==. When I call urlEncode the url to which I send https post request is: https://sandbox.payza.com/sandbox/ipn2.ashx?token=Ol9iQHrpsqdMslcnMlJJyGayVDs5gWZbjNBjlkeRI0DQ5nASh8mj7u/u3amfn2Q2mLF0Aq4FhfipNO6DZCHXJA==.

Comment: @PayzaIntegration Welcome to SO! Typically, the tradition here when replying to further questions in comments is to edit the original answer and add to it (yes, it does make the answer long sometimes; that's OK). For clarity it is also typical to quote the comment that spawned the question; it helps future readers with context and also comments can always be deleted (causing confusion). Thanks for your posts!

Comment: Hi @JasonC, thanks for the pointers, still learning the ropes here.

Comment: Hi @mitko.berbatov, can you please send an email to our team so that they can investigate? If you have sent one already, you should have a response shortly.